# Docker images won't start sometime and it error logs says something I cannot understand

Tags: docker, processmaker

I am trying to start back a Process Maker image I have in docker but it won't start. I have tried `docker start`, `docker start`. I have even tried the id of the image instead of the image name.

The log when I do `docker logs processmaker` say:

```
[Tue Mar 14 11:20:00.953960 2017] [:crit] [pid 11] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: AH00141: Could not initialize random number generator
httpd (pid 11) already running
```

Have anyone any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: post `docker ps` and `docker ps -a` and `docker logs failing_container` may help too

Comment: What's the output of `echo $PATH` inside the container? (if your unable to start it you can try to perform RUN echo $PATH in the dockerfile or show your dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

somehow only docker stop down does not worked for me. 
Best solution for me so far was make a bash file like given below. tested many times myself it did the needed hack.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# chmod +x start_dockers.sh
# ./start_dockers.sh

sudo docker-compose down

#stop all containers
sudo docker stop $(docker ps -aq)

sudo docker-compose up --build
```